# Code Changes While Keeping Large Objects In Memory in Python

Tags: python

I have an application that starts by loading a large pickled trie (173M) from disk and then uses it to do some processing.  I'm making frequent changes to the processing part, which is inconvenient because loading the trie takes 15 minutes or so.  I'm looking for a way to eliminate the repeated loading during testing, since the trie never changes.

One thing I can't do is use a smaller version of the trie.

Ideas I've had so far are memcached and turning the trie into a web service that accepts a query and returns the data I need.

What I'm looking for is the least-effort path to a situation in which I can repeatedly change and reload the processing code while maintaining access to the in-memory trie.  A direct reference to the tree would be preferable since this would require minimal code changes, but really I'm looking to minimize overall effort.

Comment: any particular reason a database wouldn't work?

Comment: I can't think of a reason that it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Pythons built-in [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) method or the [livecoding](http://code.google.com/p/livecoding/) project.

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem with `reload` is that instances stay bound to the old version of the class. If you are not keeping old instances around, `reload` is simple and works very well.

Comment: Right - I assumed this would be the case and modified my code to construct a new instance of a class in the reloaded module after reloading.  It's the only part of the module that I need, and I only need one, so it works well.